# How to focus function so it show the focused first in Kotlin

Tags: function, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog

so, i dont know how to focus function by calling the function name in onCreate. in my case i try to make alertdialog when button clicked but edittext email and pass was empty, it show allertdialog my first function and then second function. so how to focus the first function to show?

this is the code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)
    binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    //toast&snackbar dengan kondisi
    binding.tvGoToSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        emptyEmailValidation()
        emptyPassValidation()
    }
}

private fun emptyEmailValidation(): Boolean {
    val email = binding.etEmailSignIn.text.toString()

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        val dialogEmail = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogEmail.setTitle("String")
        dialogEmail.setMessage("String")
        dialogEmail.show()
        return false
    }else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        val dialogValid = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogValid.setTitle("String")
        dialogValid.setMessage("String")
        dialogValid.show()
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}

private fun emptyPassValidation(): Boolean {
    val pass = binding.etPassSignIn.text.toString()

    if (pass.isEmpty()) {
        val dialogEmail = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogEmail.setTitle("String")
        dialogEmail.setMessage("String")
        dialogEmail.show()
        return false
    }else if (pass.length < 8){
        val dialogValid = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogValid.setTitle("String")
        dialogValid.setMessage("String")
        dialogValid.show()
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)
    binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.tvGoToSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        if (!isEmailValid()){
            showDialog("Invalid Email","Please enter valid email.")
        }else if (!isPassValid()){
            showDialog("Invalid Password","Please enter valid password.")
        }else{
            // some task 
        }
    }
}

private fun isEmailValid(): Boolean {
    val email = binding.etEmailSignIn.text.toString()
    return !(email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
}

private fun isPassValid(): Boolean {
    val pass = binding.etPassSignIn.text.toString()
    return !(pass.isEmpty() || pass.length < 8)
}

private fun showDialog(title:String, msg:String){
    val dialogValid = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    dialogValid.setTitle(title)
    dialogValid.setMessage(msg)
    dialogValid.show()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).